# Linear algebra of state space representation won't be linear (superposition theorem)...

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling, control-theory

After answering [a question about calculating the state space representation of a circuit with 3 sources in it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150422/transfer-functions-with-constant-voltage-sources-in-them/150479#150479) (the circuit is there), I had a doubt - while checking, it became clear there is something wrong somewhere.

### What has been done

So I solved the circuit for each one of the sources powered ON at a time. I ended up with 3 differential equations (numbered with $i=1...3$):
$$\alpha_{i}\ddot{V_o}+\beta_{i}\dot{V_o}+\gamma_i{V_o}=\delta_iU_i$$
Where $U_i$ is the powered source value.

The superposition theorem should enable me to sum these differential equations together, such that:
$$\ddot{V_o}+a_{1}\dot{V_o}+a_2{V_o}=b_{1}I_i+b_2V_1+b_3V_2$$
With
$$a_2=\frac{\gamma_1}{\alpha_1}+\frac{\gamma_2}{\alpha_2}+\frac{\gamma_3}{\alpha_3}$$
$$a_1=\frac{\beta_1}{\alpha_1}+\frac{\beta_2}{\alpha_2}+\frac{\beta_3}{\alpha_3}$$
$$b_i=\frac{\delta_i}{\alpha_i}$$
Which is represented in state space
$$\dot{X}=AX+BU$$
$$V_o=CX+DU$$
By
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
-a_2 & -a_1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
$$C=[1, 0]$$
$$D=[0,0,0]$$
For a state vector $$X=\begin{bmatrix}
V_o\\ 
\dot{V_o}
\end{bmatrix}$$
And input vector
$$U=\begin{bmatrix}
I_i\\ 
V_1\\
V_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I've made a sanity-check of each of my elementary differential equations in steady state ($V_o=\delta_i/\gamma_i*U_i$) and they're all right. Then tested each one of them in their own state space Simulink block, which looked good.

### Question

The total state space block though, filled in the same way as the elementary differential equations but based on the sum of the differential equations instead, is totally wrong: e.g. if I'm supposed to get 100 out for 100 in in steady state, I end up with 32.

There must be an error somewher, and from those clues I would lean towards transforming to state space. But where?

This should be enough to tell me if it's something fundamental - if all seems good though, I can upload pictures of my notes.

Here is to illustrate: the upper state space model contains the total differential equation, and the 3 others are the differential equations of the cricuit for each power source.

[image]

Comment: What is inside those state space models?

Comment: I updated my post with what's inside, basically the 3 elementary differential equations on the one hand and the sum of all of those on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your logic the total differential equation should start with $3 \ddot{V}_0$. But I think you misinterpreted the Superposition Theorem. It states that if you have $y_i$ output for $u_i$ input, then you will have $\sum_i y_i$ output for $\sum_i u_i$ input, *for a given system*, i.e. for a single differential equation. What you have is 3 independent differential equations and you can't just "sum" them. You need to see that these are different equations and each of them has 2 states like following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{V}_{01} \\ \ddot{V}_{01} \\ \dot{V}_{02} \\ \ddot{V}_{02} \\ \dot{V}_{03} \\ \ddot{V}_{03} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -\gamma_1/\alpha_1 & -\beta_1/\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\gamma_2/\alpha_2 & -\beta_2/\alpha_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\gamma_3/\alpha_3 & -\beta_3/\alpha_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}{V}_{01} \\ \dot{V}_{01} \\ {V}_{02} \\ \dot{V}_{02} \\ {V}_{03} \\ \dot{V}_{03} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \delta_1/\alpha_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \delta_2/\alpha_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \delta_3/\alpha_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}I_1 \\ V_1 \\ V_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ y = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{V}_{01} \\ \dot{V}_{01} \\ {V}_{02} \\ \dot{V}_{02} \\ {V}_{03} \\ \dot{V}_{03} \end{bmatrix}$$

To see why summing up the differential equations won't work, consider these equations:

$$\dot{x}(t) + 2x(t) = u(t) \\ \dot{x}(t) + 3x(t) = u(t)$$

where $u(t)$ is the step function and $x(0)=0$. These equations have the solutions $(1-e^{-2t})/2$ and $(1-e^{-3t})/3$ respectively. Summing these equations yields the following equation

$$2\dot{x}(t) + 5x(t) = 2u(t)$$

which has the solution $2(1-e^{-5t/2})/5$, which is not the sum of the solutions of the above equations.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear answer. So in that case, the matrix C is [1 0 1 0 1 0] for y_total=y1+y2+y3, right? Also, shouldn't the 1's in the B matrix be replaced with delta_i/alpha_i (i from 1 to 3)?

Comment: And spot on about the factor 3, that one was a stupid mistake.

Comment: @MisterMystère You are right. I fixed the answer.

Comment: I modified my answer quoted above if you want to take a quick look - of course, you are mentioned.

Comment: By the way, I'm wondering what to do to set initial conditions. I assume I can't set one V_0 to, say, 230 volts; and the others at 0 because the derivatives depend on V_0 so that will make the 3 equations incoherent right? But I can't set all of them to the same value as the sum will be 3 times that. And if I subtract 2 times that, all the other values will be corrupted. So what to do then?

Comment: You need both $V_{0i}(0)$ and $\dot{V}_{0i}(0)$ for $i=1,2,3$ to uniquely solve the equations. In general, if you have $n$th order ordinary differential equation, you need $n-1$ initial conditions to obtain a unique solution.

Comment: I meant, say I know what V_0 and its derivative are at t=0, but since each elementary differential equation is only a mathematical tool I don't know what the initial conditions breakdown is. Then I can't set initial conditions?

Comment: Are you trying to say you don't know the initial conditions in a real world application? In real world sometimes you may assume that the system is at rest initially, i.e. all initial values are 0, if you have a priori information about the system like when you turn on an electronic circuit. If you have no information about the initial states of the system, you may design an observer to estimate the states from the output measurements. These solutions helps us understand the system behavior for any possible initial condition.

Comment: I'm trying to say I know what the overall V_0 is at t=0s - let's call it K-, but not the individual V_Oi at t=0s. I could set V01 and V02 and V03 to K/3 at t=0 but I'm not sure it's not going to corrupt how the model behaves before reaching steady state. At t=0s the system is at rest so all derivatives are 0.